# headers parameters in http::getUrl

Tags: tcl

I am passing headers parameters in http::getUrl as

`-headers {Authorization {Bearer $token} Content-Type application/json}`

but it is not substituting the token value.
Right now I am creating a dict a step above, and then passing it directly
`-headers $data`

It their any way to pass the value directly, where variable substitution occurs

Answer (score 3):

This is because string in `{}` are not evaluated, so you have 2 way here.

The first is using the list command:

```
-headers [list \
             Authorization [list Bearer $token] \
             Content-Type application/json ]
```

The second is by the subst command:

```
-headers [subst -nocommands \
           {Authorization {Bearer $token} Content-Type application/json}]
```

The first method is the proper to be used as it is the equivalent to the OP example, just a different expression of a list.

The purpose of the second way, is in case you have the parameter input as a variable, and could not change the format in your code.

Notice that the case with `subst` works on a string and not a list as the previous method.

It should work the same as a string could be converted to a list easy:

```
$ tclsh
% set x "A B C D"
A B C D
% lindex $x 0
A
%
```

As you see the variable `x` is a string, but you could access as it is a list without problems.

Comment: I'd _strongly_ recommend the first one; the second can have unexpected behaviour if the token contains list metacharacters (`{` and `}` particularly).

Comment: Right, thanks, I explained better this part, and the difference with the 2 methods.